# Sending messages between independent threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, messaging

I understand this simple example (taken from the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-02-message-passing.html)):

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let val = String::from("hi");
        tx.send(val).unwrap();
    });

    let received = rx.recv().unwrap();
    println!("Got: {}", received);
}
```

The channel's sender is moved to the newly spawned thread and this new thread can then use the sender to send a message via the channel.  Then the original thread can receive from the channel and get the message.

Edited after feedback from @Stargateur:

But what about a more complicated example where there are many threads.  How do each of the threads get the `sender` to be able to message all of the other threads?  Are all of the channels meant to be created for all of the threads of the program during the program startup in `main()`?  So if (for example) there is 50 threads in the program there are meant to be 50 channels created in `main()`?  And then all 50 threads would each have a clone of the 50 senders?

For example, if there were only 4 threads is it meant to be done like this?

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let (sender1, receiver1) = mpsc::channel();
    let (sender2, receiver2) = mpsc::channel();
    let (sender3, receiver3) = mpsc::channel();
    let (sender4, receiver4) = mpsc::channel();

    let builder1 = thread::Builder::new().name("thread1".into());
    builder1.spawn(move || {
        loop {
            // Am I meant to make a copy of every sender here so I can message whichever thread I need to?
            let sender1 = sender1.clone();
            let sender2 = sender2.clone();
            let sender3 = sender3.clone();
            let sender4 = sender4.clone();

            let val = String::from("hi");
            sender2.send(val).unwrap();

            if let Ok(received) = receiver1.try_recv() {
                println!("Got: {}", received);
            }
        }
    });

    let builder2 = thread::Builder::new().name("thread2".into());
    builder2.spawn(move || {
        loop {
            // Am I meant to make a copy of every sender here so I can message whichever thread I need to?
            let sender1 = sender1.clone();
            let sender2 = sender2.clone();
            let sender3 = sender3.clone();
            let sender4 = sender4.clone();

            let val = String::from("hi");
            sender1.send(val).unwrap();

            if let Ok(received) = receiver2.try_recv() {
                println!("Got: {}", received);
            }
        }
    });

    let builder3 = thread::Builder::new().name("thread3".into());
    builder3.spawn(move || {
        loop {
            // Am I meant to make a copy of every sender here so I can message whichever thread I need to?
            let sender1 = sender1.clone();
            let sender2 = sender2.clone();
            let sender3 = sender3.clone();
            let sender4 = sender4.clone();

            let val = String::from("hi");
            sender2.send(val).unwrap();

            if let Ok(received) = receiver3.try_recv() {
                println!("Got: {}", received);
            }
        }
    });

    let builder4 = thread::Builder::new().name("thread4".into());
    builder4.spawn(move || {
        loop {
            // Am I meant to make a copy of every sender here so I can message whichever thread I need to?
            let sender1 = sender1.clone();
            let sender2 = sender2.clone();
            let sender3 = sender3.clone();
            let sender4 = sender4.clone();

            let val = String::from("hi");
            sender2.send(val).unwrap();

            if let Ok(received) = receiver4.try_recv() {
                println!("Got: {}", received);
            }
        }
    });

    loop {}
}
```

So far to achieve something like this I've been putting the `sender` of the second thread into a [lazy static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static).  Then the first thread can get the `sender` out of the lazy static and send the messages to the second thread.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want do https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77b8bb2cc11a85243a8c023a6f25b204

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur but my "complicated" example is still a simplified example of my real, much larger, application.  In the real application there are many threads, so I'm looking for how this would be implemented?  Both of our examples are still quite simple.
Expanding on your example, would it be expected that when main starts, a channel is created for every thread when main() runs?

Comment: I have a production application that use a lot of task that handle millions of SIP packet and I just create all my channel like my example, so if you want a good answer you need to improve your question a lot.

Comment: I've tried to make my question clearer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I feel like part of the difficulty here is that the question focuses so heavily on threads instead of the objective of the code. If you have 50 threads, maybe you need 50 channels, maybe you only need one. It depends on what logic the thread needs to perform. Do you really need every to be able to read from every other thread? Maybe it would be better to have a hierarchy of channels, or maybe it would make sense to use a threadpool and adjust the your logic to be focused on tasks to perform instead of what thread the logic runs on. As is the answer to this question is "yes clone the channels".

Comment: well, you could do that https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4bec77ad22880fe0070287ec796be3d

Comment: It is unclear whether you want each thread to be able to broadcast to all the threads or be able to individually send messages to each of them.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  No I do not want/need to broadcast to all threads.  During operation of a thread it may need to ask another thread to do a task etc.  The main point of my question is, if there are many threads, how do others set up their program so that any thread can message any other single thread?

Comment: For "ask another thread", does it actually need to have a direct channel to that other thread for instance though, or could it always send a message to the main thread and leave it to the main thread to foward it to the destination thread? Then the individual threads don't have to message eachother, just the main thread, and the main thread forwards the message on. There are many architectural ways messages could flow between threads, whether you use N^2 channels or N+1 channels.